# If you have Sanctuary cast on you, does casting Glibness on yourself end the Sanctuary spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Would casting the Glibness spell on yourself count as "casting a spell that affects the enemy creature", for the purpose of determining whether a Sanctuary spell on you ends? Or is it simply a personal buff?

I feel like the latter is the case, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The *glibness* spell has the following characteristic:

> Range: Self

Also, it does not target or affect any other creature on its own. Thus it would not break *sanctuary*.